# iPhone - Problem with NSThread and NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, nsthread

In my iphone application, i'm creating NSThread and running some code. In the same thread, I'm using NSURLConnection and trying to get some data from server. I implemented all the delegates related to connection. In the thread i also had the following code to wait for completion of getting data from server:

```
while (threadFinished == NO) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]; 
}
```

But its crashing immediate next line to above code. Its just saying EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
Can some one guide me infixing the issue.